# Sieve of Eratosthenes in Rust

Tags: performance, primes, rust, sieve-of-eratosthenes

This is a relatively simple implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes in Rust. The main objective is to find the \$n\$th prime quickly when \$n\$ might grow to huge numbers.

```
pub fn nth(n: u32) -> u32 {
    // A convenient variable that will help in simplifying a complicated expression
    let x = if n <= 10 { 10.0 } else { n as f64 };

    // The prime counting function is pi(x) which is approximately x/ln(x)
    // We need the inverse of that. A good estimate is ceil(x * ln(x * ln(x)))
    let limit: usize = (x * (x * (x).ln()).ln()).ceil() as usize;
    let mut sieve = vec![true; limit];
    let mut count = 0;

    // Exceptional case for 0 and 1
    sieve[0] = false;
    sieve[1] = false;

    for prime in 2..limit {
        if !sieve[prime] {
            continue;
        }
        if count == n {
            return prime as u32;
        }
        count += 1;

        for multiple in ((2 * prime)..limit).step_by(prime) {
            sieve[multiple] = false;
        }
    }
    return <u32>::max_value();
}
```

This entire function would be present in `main.rs` or `lib.rs`, as necessary.

Please feel free to nitpick on any aspect of the code. Suggestions to make the code cleaner or more efficient are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice use of the Prime Number Theorem there. However, there are some issues with your code as is:

- The name `nth` does not convey the meaning of the function.
- A `return` statement is used instead of an expression at the end of the function.
- The composite marking can start at `prime * prime`, as all smaller composites are already marked by previous primes.
- The \$\left(2^{32}-1\right)\text{th}\$ prime is larger than \$2^{32}-1\$, but less than \$2^{64}-1\$, so `u64` is a better return type.
- The function will use a lot of memory if we use `<u32>::max_value()` as input.
- The [first (\$1\text{st}\$) prime number \$p_1\$ is \$2\$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=first%20prime), but your code returns \$3\$ on `nth(1)`.
- The behaviour is not documented at the moment, as the function is missing [all documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch14-02-publishing-to-crates-io.html#making-useful-documentation-comments).
- **The function doesn't necessarily return a prime number.**

The last issue is the greatest one, to be honest. If I use a `nth_prime` function, I expect the function to return a prime number and only a prime number, whereas `<u32>::max_value()` is a composite. If it's possible that your function does not return a valid result, use `Option` or `Result` instead:

````
// https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4d6abc78a8c0d205da57a17c02201d7c&version=stable&mode=release&edition=2015

/// Returns the nth prime.
///
/// It uses a sieve internally, with a size of roughly
/// `n * (n.ln() + n.ln().ln()` bytes. As a result, its
/// runtime is also bound loglinear by the upper term.
///
/// # Examples
///
/// ```
/// use <yourcrate>::nth_prime;
///
/// assert_eq!(nth_prime(0), None);
/// assert_eq!(nth_prime(1), Some(2));
/// assert_eq!(nth_prime(2), Some(3));
/// assert_eq!(nth_prime(3), Some(5));
/// ```
///
/// 
pub fn nth_prime(n: u32) -> Option<u64> {
    if n < 1 {
        return None;
    }

    // The prime counting function is pi(x) which is approximately x/ln(x)
    // A good upper bound for the nth prime is ceil(x * ln(x * ln(x)))
    let x = if n <= 10 { 10.0 } else { n as f64 };
    let limit: usize = (x * (x * (x).ln()).ln()).ceil() as usize;
    let mut sieve = vec![true; limit];
    let mut count = 0;

    // Exceptional case for 0 and 1
    sieve[0] = false;
    sieve[1] = false;

    for prime in 2..limit {
        if !sieve[prime] {
            continue;
        }
        count += 1;
        if count == n {
            return Some(prime as u64);
        }

        for multiple in ((prime * prime)..limit).step_by(prime) {
            sieve[multiple] = false;
        }
    }
    None
}
````

Note that the documentation's examples show that `0` isn't a viable index for primes, and that `nth_prime(1) == Some(2)`.

Other than that, we can optimize the code a little bit further if we consider `2` as a special case and then step `(3..limit).step_by(2)`, but that makes the code slightly harder to read. There are also several approaches to keep the memory usage limited, but they are harder to achieve.

Other than that, well done, although I'd link to the Prime Number Theorem for the approximation.

Comment: Clippy: `warning: casting u32 to f64 may become silently lossy if types change` => 'try: `f64::from(n)`' This looks silly sometimes, but really saved me more than once now

Comment: I would prefer to return a `Result` here rather than an `Option`. To me, returning `None` suggests that there *is no nth prime* (deepest apologies to Euclid), whereas returning `Err` suggests that there is something about the implementation and the particular input, that prevented it from *finding* the nth prime.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>     // Exceptional case for 0 and 1
>     sieve[0] = false;
>     sieve[1] = false;
> ```

[KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Deleting these lines of code will not affect correctness in any way, so delete them to remove distractions.

---

> ```
>     for prime in 2..limit {
>         if !sieve[prime] {
>             continue;
>         }
> ```

`sieve` is not the most helpful name, because some people write their sieves with `true` indicating a composite number and others with `true` indicating a prime number. `is_prime` would be explicit. If `!is_prime[prime]` offends your aesthetics then `prime` could also be renamed.

---

> ```
>         if count == n {
>             return prime as u32;
>         }
> ```

The need to cast here is worrying, and suggests that the types are wrong: either `limit` should be `u32` or the return value should be `u64`.

---

> The main objective is to find the \$n\$th prime quickly when \$n\$ might grow to huge numbers.

What counts as *huge*? Depending on the answer, it might make sense to trade increased complexity for a reduction in memory usage and segment the sieve. It might even be worth pre-calculating (or borrowing from resources like the [Prime Pages](https://primes.utm.edu/)) a lookup table of every millionth prime and switching to a sieve which allows you to sieve an arbitrary range rather than having to start at 2.

Comment: I agree that the names could be more descriptive. Thanks for the review!